# Anomalous Dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, renormalization

Is there a straightforward way to find the anomalous dimension of $\phi$'s for the following Lagrangian?

$$\mathcal{L}=-(\partial_{\mu}\phi_1+\partial_{\mu}\phi_2)^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}(\phi_1^4+\phi_2^4)-\frac{2\rho}{4!}\phi_1^2\phi_2^2 $$

Also, if anyone could point me out the location of any bibliographical results on this I would be thankful.